# find and remove partial duplicates in excel

Tags: vba, excel, excel-formula, array-formulas

my excel sheet have some duplicate values. i want to remove these duplicate values. Sometime i need to remove row and in some sheets only cell.
Here is the ex:

```
Cell A                    |
===============================
myphotoname.jpg           |
------------------------
myphotoname1.jpg          |
-------------------------
yourphotoname320x210.jpg  |
-------------------------
yourphotoname.jpg         |
```

I want to remove file names like "myphotoname1.jpg" and "yourphotoname320x210.jpg" . i tried remove duplicate tool in excel but its not able to work in this way. any way to find and remove these duplicate entries from excel sheet.

Comment: For two records to be considered duplicates, how many character must match ??

Comment: 5 to 10 any from these value will be ok .. thanks

Comment: Use `Left` to dictate how many characters you want to use, then look for other rows with those characters matching?

Comment: can you please explain in more details? thanks

Comment: Pretty bold username :P, especially considering you haven't shown us what you've [tried so far](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and you could use Google to get info on the `Left()` function.

Comment: If somebody downvotes, please have the courtesy to mention the reason

Comment: How is the decision made as to whether it is a single cell, or an entire row, that is to be removed?  Should a macro (if the solution is VBA) just choose one method at random, or is there more information that could be added to the question?

Comment: hi, i have two sheets in one sheet i need remove row and in 2nd i need only cell . but it does not problem , if any way to do one thing from both i will manage . if row remove  possible i will use this in both sheet and manage . if cell its also ok . thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In an unused column to the right, put this array formula¹ in the second row.

```
=ISNUMBER(MATCH(LEFT(A2, MIN(IFERROR(FIND({0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9}, A2)-1, 1E+99)))&MID(A2, FIND(".", A2), 9),A:A, 0))
```

Finalize with CSE and fill down as necessary. Use Data ► AutoFilter to filter on that column for TRUE and delete the visible rows.

[image: identify_duplicates]

---

¹ <sub>Array formulas need to be finalized with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter↵</kbd>. If entered correctly, Excel with wrap the formula in braces (e.g. **{** and **}**). You do not type the braces in yourself. Once entered into the first cell correctly, they can be filled or copied down or right just like any other formula. Try and reduce your full-column references to ranges more closely representing the extents of your actual data. Array formulas chew up calculation cycles logarithmically so it is good practise to narrow the referenced ranges to a minimum. See [Guidelines and examples of array formulas](https://support.office.com/en-ca/article/guidelines-and-examples-of-array-formulas-7d94a64e-3ff3-4686-9372-ecfd5caa57c7) for more information.</sub>

Comment: My idea was to sort descending then use `=SUMPRODUCT(ISNUMBER(SEARCH(LEFT($A2:$A$5,LEN($A2:$A$5)-4),A1))*1)`

Comment: thanks dear . lot of search in google was not able to providing answer which you provide . thanks for sharing your knowledge .. and for those who just know the press vote down button keep doing . if you not help just do down vote .. thank you too .. thanks jeeped again ..

Comment: @ScottCraner thanks dear you always try to help me .. thanks for your help